# Can you help me identify this odd fence-like brick?

Tags: part-identification

This brick was found in a selection of unopened LEGO bags left with an instruction book that were donated to my mother's workplace. Bags did not correspond to the book and and as such I am left at an impasse to find this brick as it is odd enough that I have been unable to find it so that my brother and I can obtain more of them.

[image: back]
[image: front]
[image: top]
[image: bottom]
[image: sides]

Answer (score 5):

You have part number [64448: Support 1 x 6 x 5 Girder Rectangular](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64448&idColor=7)

[image]

I'm not sure what color your piece is, but [here is a list of sets it comes in](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=64448&in=S).